# C# rerun thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to rerun thread when it finish working. I have two programs. One in Windows Form and second in cmd. Windows Form program run program in cmd.

I tried use while(true) and if with: process.HasExited, .WaitForExit, .Join on thred, .IsBusy and rerun method on RunWorkerCompleted. But it's doesn't work.

BgWorker code (action on button click):

```
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(uruchomWatek);
```

Function whitch I want to rerun thread

```
private void uruchomWatek(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    String polaczenieZDB = config.Default.adresDb + ";" + config.Default.nazwaDb + ";" + config.Default.login + ";" + config.Default.haslo;

    //przygotowuję proces 
    Process pr = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
    //uruchamiam cmd
    prs.FileName = "cmd";
    // /c START uruchamia program w cmd, przekazuję tutaj prametry
    prs.Arguments = " /c START " + " " + @sciezkaDoSlaveTextBox.Text + " " + ipAdresTextBox.Text + " "
                    + numerPortuTextBox.Text + " " + polaczenieZDB + " " + pobierzZadaniaDoSpr();
    pr.StartInfo = prs;

    //uruchamiam proces w nowym wątku
    ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(() => pr.Start());
    Thread th = new Thread(ths);
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thakns, I remove Thread.

I tried something like that
while(true)
{
if(process.HasExited)
{
start
}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class may help you through this purpose :

```
 public class BackgroundThread : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public BackgroundThread()
        {
            this.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }
        protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnDoWork(e);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //Log Exception
            }
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            if (this.IsBusy)
                return;
            this.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            this.CancelAsync();
            this.Dispose(true);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to use your class as a timer and do the task in intervals the following class may comes really handy.

```
  public class BackgroundTimer : BackgroundWorker
    {
        private ManualResetEvent intervalManualReset;
        private enum ProcessStatus { Created, Running, JobCompleted, ExceptionOccured };
        private ProcessStatus processStatus = new ProcessStatus();
        public int Interval { get; set; }

        public BackgroundTimer()
        {
            this.processStatus = ProcessStatus.Created;
            this.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this.Interval = 1000;
        }

        protected override void OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e);
            if (processStatus == ProcessStatus.ExceptionOccured)
                // Log ...  
            processStatus = ProcessStatus.JobCompleted;
        }
        protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!this.CancellationPending)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.OnDoWork(e);
                    this.Sleep();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    // Log ...
                    this.processStatus = ProcessStatus.ExceptionOccured;
                    this.Stop();
                }
            }
            if (e != null)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            this.processStatus = ProcessStatus.Running;
            if (this.IsBusy)
                return;

            this.intervalManualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            this.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            this.CancelAsync();
            this.WakeUp();
            this.Dispose(true);
        }
        public void WakeUp()
        {
            if (this.intervalManualReset != null)
                this.intervalManualReset.Set();
        }
        private void Sleep()
        {
            if (this.intervalManualReset != null)
            {
                this.intervalManualReset.Reset();
                this.intervalManualReset.WaitOne(this.Interval);
            }
        }
        public void Activate()
        {
            if (!this.IsBusy)
                // Log ...
            this.Start();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2 :**
Usage :

```
    sendThread = new BackgroundThread();
    sendThread.DoWork += sendThread_DoWork;
    sendThread.Run();
    void sendThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: First look fine, but I still don't know how to use it. I don't want to use timer, because shell program check something and I want to rerun it wehen it finish.

Comment: Ok my friend, so you should use the first class. For usage I'm about to edit my answer to explain it for you.

Comment: I did what you wrote ;-) i don't know how use it for rerun my shell program

Comment: Just call Run method whenever you want to run it again.

Comment: ok it works good. One more question. How rerun automatically. I mean rerun shell program when it finish work. first run i want to make by click, anothers automatically

Comment: Using RunWorkerCompleted event you can handle that.

Comment: it runs new shell window for infinity. doesn't wait for finish.

Comment: That's because you are using a thread inside your background worker. Background worker itself acts like a thread.You should put your code inside BackGroundworker_DoWork method.

Comment: I remove thread. I think its because it get run cmd for finish, not wait for end program indide. If I change cmd on Environment.SpecialFolder.System its rerun when I close System window

Comment: Ok it works. I add Process.Start(prs).WaitForExit(); :-)